# Wrapper method for ConfigureAwait(false)?

Tags: .net, async

Does it make sense to declare a async method as private and then create a public method to act as a wrapper that calls the private method with `ConfigureAwait(false)`?

The intended purpose is design an intuitive API that hides complexities and doesn't require the user of the API to have to think about ConfigureAwait.

Is this called anything? Is it a design pattern?

Is this common?

```csharp
public class Example
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        FooAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    private async Task FooAsync()
    {
        // var x = await ...
        // Something(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a design pattern. I would call it a design decision. I think you should ask if hiding ConfigureAwait(false) as a default API behavior does present any danger. Also you can try asking it on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: `ConfigureAwait` affect following `await`. If there are no await, then it does nothing.

Comment: Did you miss something in copying? Your code does not make much sense.Your public method has no `async` anymore and does not `await` anything. It does not even call `.Result`.

Comment: @nvoigt, No. The public method should not be async, as it uses ConfigureAwait(false).

Comment: Why would you offer *only* a synchronous API, when that API is going to call async functions on the same object? I could understand giving both options, but not like this.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Because some things the API user never want to await. Example `FooAsync` performs an action after doing a Task.Delay for 10 seconds. The API user don't want to use await for that and be stalled while Task.Delay is delaying.

Comment: I don't think `ConfigureAwait` means what you think it means.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I think it means to run the method in the background without awaiting for it to return.

Comment: @Fred `ConfigureAwait` can not affect execution of `FooAsync` because it is called only after `FooAsync` return its `Task` object. It configure following `await` to use default synchronization context when it schedule continuation. If you are not use `await` on result of `ConfigureAwait` then it practically do nothing, apart from wasting some CPU cycles.

Comment: @PetSerAl, Thanks. That makes sense. It appears I was mistaken about this. I was thinking about doing something like `Task.Delay` then run something after that. But I didn't want to halt execution of the entire program.